# Why does my uploaded YouTube audio sound muffled?

Tags: youtube, audio

long time lurker here in need of assistance.
I created a video and it’s  a montage of various videos I own. The mp4 plays fine but as soon as I upload it to YouTube one of the montage clips goes mute. It’s not completely silent, there’s  scratchy muffled low frequency sound. If I plug my headphones in the whole thing sounds normal but without, that one piece of footage isn’t right.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you